# Calculating duration of colliding events on a timeline with a capacity per hour

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time

I would like to create a timeline of colliding events where the events represent a certain amount of kg to be processed and the timeline has a certain capacity per hour. The events have a static start time but the end time is calculated based on the weight to be processed and the capacity of the timeline.

I have tried to calculate the delay in hours but it has not the output I expect.

```
const kgPerHourSpeed = 1000;

const events = [
    { startDateTime: '2024-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: null, overlappingDelayHours: 0, kg: 1000 },
    { startDateTime: '2024-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: null, overlappingDelayHours: 0, kg: 1000 },
    { startDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: null, overlappingDelayHours: 0, kg: 1000 },
];

const calculateEndDateTime = (startDateTime, kg) => {
    const hours = kg / kgPerHourSpeed;
    const start = new Date(startDateTime);
    start.setHours(start.getHours() + hours);
    console.log(start);
    return start;
}

// Iterate through events to calculate overlappingDelayHours
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    const event1 = events[i];
    endDateTime1 = calculateEndDateTime(event1.startDateTime, event1.kg);
    events[i].endDateTime = endDateTime1.toISOString();

    for (let j = i + 1; j < events.length; j++) {
        const event2 = events[j];
        const endDateTime2 = calculateEndDateTime(event2.startDateTime, event2.kg);
        const startDateTime2 = new Date(event2.startDateTime);

        // If event2 starts before event1 ends, they overlap
        if (startDateTime2 < endDateTime1) {
            const overlappingDuration = endDateTime1 - startDateTime2;
            const overlappingDelayHours = overlappingDuration / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            events[i].overlappingDelayHours += overlappingDelayHours;
            events[j].overlappingDelayHours += overlappingDelayHours;
        }
    }
}

console.log(events);
```

Output: it results in the wrong output because when including the delay, the third event would also have to collide

```
0: {startDateTime: '2024-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', overlappingDelayHours: 1, kg: 1000}
1: {startDateTime: '2024-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', overlappingDelayHours: 1, kg: 1000}
2: {startDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: '2024-01-01T11:00:00.000Z', overlappingDelayHours: 0, kg: 1000}
```

Expected output:

```
0: {startDateTime: '2024-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', overlappingDelayHours: 3, kg: 1000}
1: {startDateTime: '2024-01-01T09:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', overlappingDelayHours: 3, kg: 1000}
2: {startDateTime: '2024-01-01T10:00:00.000Z', endDateTime: '2024-01-01T11:00:00.000Z', overlappingDelayHours: 2, kg: 1000}
```

How to write an algorithm in JavaScript (or a similar language if you prefer) to calculate how long each event takes to finish based on its weight and the timeline capacity? If items collide they should share the capacity per hour for the time they are overlapping. Any direction in how to approach this is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please share some sample input data and desired output.  Also show something about the attempts you've made so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do think there's an interesting question lurking here.  Please [edit] to add more information and I for one will vote to reopen.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you, I have added more information

Comment: I'm hoping another "reopen" vote is recorded soon.  But in the meanwhile, I had tried on my own making guesses that don't exactly match your updated example.  But it might still be helpful:  http://link.fourwindssoft.com/102.  If I see this reopened, I will try to add this as an answer.

Comment: your expected output is the same as the input in terms of end date. also as i understand, the new events should be started being processed immediately so the other events would get less capacity to share it with the new event?

Comment: We seem to be stuck with two reopen votes here.  And additional edit with a little more information might get a third vote.

Comment: @ScottSauyet it's not clear whether FIFO or equal amount of capacity should be implemented. If i'm missing something please point me

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev: I think you'd have to ask the OP.  I assumed equal capacity, as that's the more challenging implementation.  But it's possible that there's some different alternative altogether.  (And if you vote to reopen, we might get more discussion, unless you're the other one who already has!)

Comment: @ScottSauyet i was the first to reopen

Comment: Well, now there are two of us!

Comment: @ScottSauyet ping. posted my solution and benchmarked with yours

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I had seen yours and wrote mine up, accidentally leaving it in preview when I went off to lunch.  Your message came in about four minutes after that!  I haven't looked carefully at your code yet, only running it to see that it works.  I am generally much less concerned than you are with performance, so I don't pay a lot of attention to benchmarks until I Know much more about the functional and non-functional requirements.

Comment: @ScottSauyet i dont mind whether functional or not approach is used. just noticed my algo is linear and yours isnt but didnt check why. i care about time complexity though

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Sauyet has suggested, the events share the capacity equally. Made with the same test data as the Scott Sauyet's. It modifies the original array and events, but it's easy to make a copy of original data.

```js
const solution = (events, capacity) => {
    events.sort((a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime);
    events.forEach(e => e.remaining = e.kg);
    const currentEvents = new Set;
    let nextIdx = 0;
    let currentTime;
    while (nextIdx < events.length) {
        if (!currentEvents.size) {
            const next = events[nextIdx++];
            currentEvents.add(next);
            currentTime = next.startTime;
        }
        let next = events[nextIdx];
        while (currentEvents.size) {
            const perEvent = capacity / 60 / currentEvents.size;
            let shortest = next ? next.startTime - currentTime : Infinity;
            currentEvents.forEach(e => {
                const remainingTime = e.remaining / perEvent;
                if (remainingTime < shortest) shortest = remainingTime;
            });
            currentEvents.forEach(e => {
                e.remaining -= perEvent * shortest;
                if (!e.remaining) {
                    delete e.remaining;
                    e.endTime = currentTime + shortest;
                    currentEvents.delete(e);
                }
            });
            if (next?.startTime - currentTime === shortest) {
                currentEvents.add(events[nextIdx++]);
                next = events[nextIdx];
            }
            currentTime += shortest;
        }
    }
    return events;
};

console.log(solution ( [
    {id: 'a', kg: 8, startTime: 1},   
    {id: 'b', kg: 40, startTime: 5},
    {id: 'c', kg: 12, startTime: 9},
    {id: 'd', kg: 20, startTime: 16},
    {id: 'e', kg: 4, startTime: 17},
    {id: 'f', kg: 12, startTime: 27}
], 240))
```

And benchmark

```
` Chrome/122
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                    n=6       |      n=60      |      n=600      |     n=1200     
Alexander      1.00x x100k 156 | 1.00x x10k 113 |  1.00x  x1k 106 |   1.00x x1k 219
Scott Sauyet   3.10x x100k 483 | 6.11x x10k 690 | 37.36x x100 396 | 149.77x x10 328
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let chunkId = -99;
const $chunks = [1, 10, 100, 200];
const $chunk = () => {
    chunkId += 100;
    return [
        { id: 'a', kg: 8, startTime: 1 * chunkId },
        { id: 'b', kg: 40, startTime: 5 * chunkId },
        { id: 'c', kg: 12, startTime: 9 * chunkId },
        { id: 'd', kg: 20, startTime: 16 * chunkId },
        { id: 'e', kg: 4, startTime: 17 * chunkId },
        { id: 'f', kg: 12, startTime: 27 * chunkId }
    ];
};

const $input = [];

// Helper function for sorting
const byStart = (a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime

// Main (recursive) function
//   capacity: total capacity
//   evennts: {id, kg: load, startTime: minutes since beginning}
//   time: minutes since start
//   open: events that have started but not completed, inlude `remaining` field
//   closed: events that have finished, now with `endTime` as well
const process = (capacity, events, time, open, closed) => {
    // return the (sorted) closed events when completed
    if (events.length == 0 && open.length == 0)
        return closed.sort(byStart);
    // how much of the capacity each event gets -- possibly too naive
    const capacityShare = capacity / 60 / (open.length || 1)
    // how long this runs before the next event starts or a running one finishes (minutes)
    const interval = Math.min(
        (events[0] || { startTime: Infinity }).startTime - time,
        ...open.map(({ remaining }) => remaining / capacityShare)
    )
    // how much of each running event is processed during this interval
    const perEvent = capacityShare * interval
    // the events that are closed at the end of this interval
    const newClosed = open
        .filter(({ remaining }) => remaining <= perEvent)
        .map(({ remaining, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, endTime: time + interval }))
    // the remaining open events after we close the completed ones, with updated remaining kgs
    const newOpen = open
        .filter(({ remaining }) => remaining > perEvent)
        .map(({ remaining, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest, remaining: remaining - perEvent }))
    // the queued events that are opened for the next interval
    const startingEvents = events
        .filter(({ startTime }) => startTime == time + interval)
        .map(e => ({ ...e, remaining: e.kg }))
    // the remaining queued events after opening the approriate ones
    const queuedEvents = events
        .filter(({ startTime }) => startTime != time + interval)

    // recur using these newly calculated values
    return process(
        capacity,
        queuedEvents,
        time + interval,
        [...newOpen, ...startingEvents],
        [...closed, ...newClosed]
    )
}

// public function, just wraps `process`
const solution = (capacity, events) =>
    process(capacity, [...events].sort(byStart), 0, [], [])

const solution3 = (events, capacity) => {
    events.sort((a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime);
    events.forEach(e => e.remaining = e.kg);
    const currentEvents = new Set;
    let nextIdx = 0;
    let currentTime;
    while (nextIdx < events.length) {
        if (!currentEvents.size) {
            const next = events[nextIdx++];
            currentEvents.add(next);
            currentTime = next.startTime;
        }
        let next = events[nextIdx];
        while (currentEvents.size) {
            const perEvent = capacity / 60 / currentEvents.size;
            let shortest = next ? next.startTime - currentTime : Infinity;
            currentEvents.forEach(e => {
                const remainingTime = e.remaining / perEvent;
                if (remainingTime < shortest) shortest = remainingTime;
            });
            currentEvents.forEach(e => {
                e.remaining -= perEvent * shortest;
                if (!e.remaining) {
                    delete e.remaining;
                    e.endTime = currentTime + shortest;
                    currentEvents.delete(e);
                }
            });
            if (next?.startTime - currentTime === shortest) {
                currentEvents.add(events[nextIdx++]);
                next = events[nextIdx];
            }
            currentTime += shortest;
        }
    }
    return events;
}
// @benchmark Scott Sauyet
solution(240, $input)

//@benchmark Alexander
solution3($input, 240);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: Can you explain what your benchmark is supposed to do? I see your closed-source tool, but with no explanation of how `$chunk`/`$chunks`/`$input` are supposed to work, it's hard to get any understanding.  And what does `n` represent here.  To check algorithmic complexity, presumably this would  have to vary with the number of events, but the `$chunks` code seems to be varying the start-time, which should be irrelevant.  And what does the last number in each cell of the output represent?  It's not at all clear to me.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thanks for feedback, i'll start writing documention tomorrow. the orange field is how slower a solution (1.00x - the fastest in a column). The gray field - number of cycles of code run, green - milliseconds to run the cycles. n=6 - number of items in an array. $chunk - function to fill $input, $chunks - array of how many $chunk calls to perform to fill $input (default [1,10,100,1000] but i wasnt able to complete your algo with n=6000 (1000x), so lowered it to 200

Comment: Any progress on the documentation?

Comment: @ScottSauyet made it as a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78190163/how-to-use-silentmantra-benchmark

Comment: you'll see a bump in speed using `for..of` instead of `.forEach` which uses a stack frame and return pointer

Comment: @Mulan rather in FF, afaik Chrome has it optimized, i'll test though

Answer (score 0):

This recursive version works by checking the first end time for any running task, as well as the start time of the next starting tasks, and choosing the earliest time among them.  Then it adds all completed tasks at that time to the `closed` list, moves the appropriate tasks to the `open` queue, and recurs.  It terminates when there are no unstarted or open tasks, returning the `closed` list.

```js
// Helper function for sorting
const byStart = (a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime

const process = (capacity, events, {
  time = 0, open = [], closed = [],
  capacityShare = capacity / 60 / (open.length || 1),
  interval = Math.min(
    (events[0] || {startTime: Infinity}).startTime - time, 
    ...open.map(({remaining}) => remaining / capacityShare)
  ),
  perEvent = capacityShare * interval,
} = {}) => (events.length == 0 && open.length == 0)
  ? closed.sort(byStart)
  :  process(
       capacity, 
       events.filter(({startTime}) => startTime != time + interval), 
       {
          time: time + interval, 
          open: [
            ...open.filter(({remaining}) => remaining > perEvent).map(({remaining, ...rest}) => ({...rest, remaining: remaining - perEvent})), 
            ...events.filter(({startTime}) => startTime == time + interval).map(e => ({...e, remaining: e.kg}))
          ], 
          closed: [
            ...closed, 
            ...open.filter(({remaining}) => remaining <= perEvent).map(({remaining, ...rest}) => ({...rest, endTime: time + interval}))
          ]
       }
    )

// demo call -- returns new events, not mutated ones.
console.log(process (240, [
  {id: 'a', kg: 8, startTime: 1},   
  {id: 'b', kg: 40, startTime: 5},
  {id: 'c', kg: 12, startTime: 9},
  {id: 'd', kg: 20, startTime: 16},
  {id: 'e', kg: 4, startTime: 17},
  {id: 'f', kg: 12, startTime: 27}
]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

It returns the following:

```
//  [
//    /* Idle from 0 - 1 */
//    {id:"a", kg:8,  "startTime": 1,  endTime: 3 },
//    /* Idle from 3 - 5 */
//    {id:"b", kg:40, "startTime": 5,  endTime: 21},
//    {id:"c", kg:12, "startTime": 9,  endTime: 15},
//    {id:"d", kg:20, "startTime": 16, endTime: 24},
//    {id:"e", kg:4,  "startTime": 17, endTime: 20},
//    /* Idle from 24 - 27 */
//    {id:"f", kg:12, "startTime": 27, endTime: 30},
//    /* Idle after 30 */
//   ]
```

Which looks something like this (and please forgive my ascii diagram!):

```
(time)    0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30----->
     / a:    |-----|
    /  b:                |-----------------------------------------------|
(evts) c:                            |-----------------|
    |  d:                                                 |-----------------------|
    \  e:                                                    |--------|
     \ f:                                                                                  |--------|
     
(time)    0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30----->
          |--|-----|-----|-----------|-----------------|--|--|--------|--|--------|--------|--------|---...
(running) |    a     |        b             b, c        d |  b, d, e   |     d        |        f       |
(capacity |   240    |       240            120       240 |     80     |    240       |       240      |
   share) |          |                                    |            |              |                |
(running) '-- (idle) '-- (idle)                    b, d --'     b, d --'     (idle) --'       (idle) --'
(capacity                                           120          120
   share)
```

This is written in my preferred style, with expressions only, no statements (except for function definitions.)  But it's a little more complex than these usually get, and if it's confusing, the following imperative version, with many statements and temporary variables as well as some comments, might be more familiar to some:

```js
// Helper function for sorting
const byStart = (a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime

// Main (recursive) function
//   capacity: total capacity
//   evennts: {id, kg: load, startTime: minutes since beginning}
//   time: minutes since start
//   open: events that have started but not completed, inlude `remaining` field
//   closed: events that have finished, now with `endTime` as well
const process = (capacity, events, time, open, closed) => {
  // return the (sorted) closed events when completed
  if (events.length == 0 && open.length == 0)
    return closed.sort(byStart)
  // how much of the capacity each event gets -- possibly too naive
  const capacityShare = capacity / 60 / (open.length || 1)
  // how long this runs before the next event starts or a running one finishes (minutes)
  const interval = Math.min(
    (events[0] || {startTime: Infinity}).startTime - time, 
    ...open.map(({remaining}) => remaining / capacityShare)
  )
  // how much of each running event is processed during this interval
  const perEvent = capacityShare * interval
  // the events that are closed at the end of this interval
  const newClosed = open
    .filter(({remaining}) => remaining <= perEvent) 
    .map(({remaining, ...rest}) => ({...rest, endTime: time + interval}))
  // the remaining open events after we close the completed ones, with updated remaining kgs
  const newOpen = open
    .filter(({remaining}) => remaining > perEvent)
    .map(({remaining, ...rest}) => ({...rest, remaining: remaining - perEvent}))
  // the queued events that are opened for the next interval
  const startingEvents = events
    .filter(({startTime}) => startTime == time + interval)
    .map(e => ({...e, remaining: e.kg}))
  // the remaining queued events after opening the approriate ones
  const queuedEvents = events
    .filter(({startTime}) => startTime != time + interval)
  
  // recur using these newly calculated values
  return process(
    capacity, 
    queuedEvents, 
    time + interval, 
    [...newOpen, ...startingEvents], 
    [...closed, ...newClosed]
  )
}

// public function, just wraps `process`
const solution = (capacity, events) =>
  process (capacity, [...events].sort(byStart), 0, [], [])

// demo call -- returns new events, not mutated ones.
console.log(solution (240, [
    {id: 'a', kg: 8, startTime: 1},   
    {id: 'b', kg: 40, startTime: 5},
    {id: 'c', kg: 12, startTime: 9},
    {id: 'd', kg: 20, startTime: 16},
    {id: 'e', kg: 4, startTime: 17},
    {id: 'f', kg: 12, startTime: 27}
]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: nice work salvaging this question, it is indeed a challenging and interesting problem. my one critique on this solution would be the heavy, repeated use of `.filter().map()`, which can be collapsed using `flatMap`, and the 2x `open.filter().map()` can be done in a single `reduce`, by returning `remaining <= perEvent` on the left, and (inductive) `remaining > perEvent` on the right. Something like `const [newClosed, newOpen] = open.reduce(([closed, open], o) => o.remaining <= perEvent ? [..., ...] : [..., ...], [[], []])`. thanks for sharing :D

Comment: @Mulan: That's funny, because I wrote it using an implementation of `filterMap`, implemented atop `flatMap`, and decided I didn't want any dependency in this one-off answer.  Then I went and extracted `byStart` anyway! :-)  I'll have to check out your `reduce` suggestion when I have time for more than a drive-by.  Thanks!  Good to "see" you again.

Comment: @Mulan, I also haven't had time to look closely at Alexander N's solution and perf tests.  I'm surprised that he gets linear time vs my quadratic.  I'll try to look at it soon-ish.