# Linear time increase per promise when resolving concurrently using Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, parallel-processing, promise.all

I have a method that steps through a JSON payload to run computation on some data within that payload. When I create 100 promises of that method and then pass them into Promise.all(), it seems that for every promise that is resolved concurrently, the next one takes a bit longer to resolve.

This is not specific to my method, I have tried a similar thing with a public API that returns simple JSON data. In calling that API concurrently using Promise.all I observed the same thing... every consecutive promise would take longer and longer to resolve.

Here is a simple code snippet to illustrate what I'm doing:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const getSomeData = async () => {
  try {
    await axios.get('https://some.api.com');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to get data...');
  }
};

const promiseList = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
  promiseList.push(new Promise(async (res) => {
    const startTime = performance.now();
    await getSomeData();
    const stopTime = performance.now();
    console.log(`time taken by promise: ${stopTime - startTime}`);
    res();
  }));
}

const main = async () => {
  const startTime = performance.now();
  await Promise.all(promiseList);
  const stopTime = performance.now();
  console.log(`total time taken: ${stopTime - startTime}`);
};

main();
```

This of course is a pretty pointless method but I created it strictly to observe how promises behave when running concurrently and how much performance benefit there is versus running sequentially (it's obviously a significant improvement).

My question is, what would cause every consecutive promise to take longer and longer until all the promises are resolved? In which case if I were to run this again, it would reset the time taken back to around 200ms for the first promise, before it started increasing again until the last promise would take around 600ms to resolve.

Is this just the nature of single threaded Javascript execution and concurrency? I am really interested in hearing a more in depth explanation of this phenomenon.

Comment: It *could* be because of single-threaded execution (profile! or at least look at CPU time), but keep in mind that throughput is not unlimited with extra parallelism on many levels, including the network path between you and the service, and the service itself. It might even be rate-limiting you intentionally.

Comment: @Ry- I will definitely do some more profiling as you suggested. In terms of rate limiting, I don't believe that is occurring because running that API sequentially takes a consistent 200ms per call up until all 100 requests are completed. However, running them concurrently starts of around 200ms each call until it increases over time. Promise.all on the API still yields results faster than the sequential approach. Same behavior is observed for my JSON querying method which has no axios calls.
Edit: Your point on throughput definitely makes sense though.

Comment: [Never use an `async function` as a `new Promise` executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! Make it an IIFE instead.

Comment: Have you tried not awaiting the data in the loop? Because of how async code is executed after any sync code is finished this may help. Also, try moving logging out of the loop as it's very slow compared to fast code; much better to compile the data and console.log once outside the loop. Since you're hitting an API it is likely rate limited, which would affect time to resolve as it slows the response. If there's any way to get multiple/all data you need at once and parse it locally that may be faster, of course dependent on many factors though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the network waterfall:
[image]

I guess your api calls just get throttled on the backend side. Your request are queued on the backend side too.

If you replace the api calls with timeouts, `Promise.all` works just fine:

```js
const getSomeData = () => {
  try {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to get data...');
  }
};

const promiseList = [];
const log = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
  promiseList.push(new Promise(async (res) => {
    const startTime = performance.now();
    await getSomeData();
    const stopTime = performance.now();
    log.push(`time taken by promise: ${stopTime - startTime}`);
    res();
  }));
}

const main = async () => {
  const startTime = performance.now();
  await Promise.all(promiseList);
  const stopTime = performance.now();
  log.forEach(l => console.log(l));
  console.log(`total time taken: ${stopTime - startTime}`);
};

main();
```

Comment: While this may be true, I have found that this applies to my JSON querying method - as mentioned in the question - as well, which contains no async operations; it's simply a recursive method. And after taking the suggestions in the comment and doing some CPU profiling, it seems to be that it truly might be that JS is single threaded since my CPU usage for the app went to 100% until all promises were resolved.

Now, the question is what can be done to improve the performance of that method. Interestingly, the method only takes 200ms to parse through over 50k lines of JSON and generate reports

Comment: @JasSingh use Workers, you can utilize multiple cores of CPU. you can fetch JSON from workers, process and then `postMessage()` to the main thread and of course JS is single threaded

Comment: @JasSingh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78109589/calculating-duration-of-colliding-events-on-a-timeline-with-a-capacity-per-hour/78137420#78137420 here you can check how workers work with CPU intensive task, run the benchmark with and without workers and see the difference

Comment: Thank you, I did do a simple implementation of workers and noticed a huge improvement as you indicated. I'll mark this as an accepted answers (unfortunately can't upvote due to reputation).